AttributedError: module ‘pyrealsense2’ has no attributed ‘pipeline’ fault on jetson nano with realsense
I am newbie and triying stream on realsense D455 cam to jetson nano 4gb hardware. I got " AttributedError: module ‘pyrealsense2’ has no attributed ‘pipeline’" error message while screaming on python method. When I use the realsense-viewer I can streaming.
I tried several method from internet and forum but I couldn’t find the way.
Can you light me?
Ubuntu 18.04
python3.6
I checked and changed the with ./bash export pythondatapath /usr/local/lib/python3.6
I tried to change the pythonpath in ./bash folder, I dublicated pyrealsense from /usr/local/lib/python3.6 to /usr/local/lib. I deleted all folder and install again several times. No response.

Welcome to SO! Please post your code and error message.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
